# Is it ok to keep multiple DataFrames in Scala List or Map for Iterative processing

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I have 3 DataFrames, each with 50 columns and millions of records. I need to apply some common transformations on the above DataFrames.

Currently, I'm keeping those DataFrames in a Scala List and performing the operations on each of them Iteratively.

My question is, Is it Ok to keep big DataFrames in Scala Collection or will it have any Performance related Issues. If yes, what is the best way to work on multiple DataFrames in an Iterative manner?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can do that, it won't have any performance impact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no issue doing so, as List is just a reference to your DataFrame and DataFrames in Spark are lazy eval.
So until and unless you start working on any of the DataFrame i.e. calling action on them they will not get populated.
And as soon as the action is finished it will be cleared up.
So it will be equal to calling them separately 3 times, hence there is no issue with your approach.